# Using a string in a while loop (OR operator)

Tags: c++

I'm working through some beginner projects and one is to create a program that only greets two certain names (Alice and Bob). I thought the best way would be to use a while loop, so as long as name wasn't equal to Bob or Alice it would keep prompting the user to input the correct names. However, the program prints the output in the while loop, even if it is Bob or Alice! I need a bit of help putting this one right. Many thanks in advance.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

int main()
{

    std::cout << "Please enter the correct name(s): ";

    std::string name = " ";
    std::cin >> name;

    while (name != "Alice" || name!= "Bob")
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the correct name(s): ";
        std::cin >> name;
    }
    if (name == "Alice")
        std::cout << "Hi Alice!" << std::endl;
    if (name == "Bob")
        std::cout << "Hi Bob!" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You mean && - and.

Comment: Seriously, this is basic logic. Shut down your computer and write _the logic_ in a human language on a piece of paper. Does it make sense? If so, try to translate it into C++.

Comment: `name != "Alice" || name!= "Bob"` will always be true since name can't be 2 things at once. It could only be false if name was equal to both "Alice" and "Bob". Think the logic through and it will make sense.

Comment: You should properly debug your code first.

Comment: Should be: (name != "Alice" && name!= "Bob")

Comment: Wow, for some reason I was adamant in my mind that && wouldn't have made sense in the context, obviously I was wrong. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, welcome to the C++ world! Now, let's move onto your problem. If you take a look at this line,

```
while (name != "Alice" || name!= "Bob")
```

As others have said, this contains the problem. You are basically saying:

```
while (the name is NOT "Alice" OR the name is NOT "Bob")
```

Names cannot be two things at once. In order to hit this condition, your name will have to be Bob Alice or Alice Bob. If you look at the following line of code

```
std::cin >> name;
```

This will be impossible. The computer is only taking one word. The condition will never hit. In order to fix this, you should do the following:

```
while (name != "Alice" && name != "Bob")
```

That will fix the problem. Also, if you would like to improve your code, you can do the following:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>

int main()
{
std::string name = "";

std::cout << "Please enter the correct name: ";
std::cin >> name;

while (name != "Alice" && name != "Bob")
{
    std::cout << "Please enter the correct name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
}

std::cout << "Hi " << name << "!" << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you for the welcome :). I'm sitting here with my head spinning about || and && operators. It's frustrating because I keep thinking OR makes sense in this context, even though it clearly doesn't! Thank you for showing me a more simple way to write the problem also

Comment: @Njgardner90, I understand where you are coming from. All of us started at  I highly recommend this [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/36-logical-operators/) to help you better understand the && and || operators.